# What is best source to learn about Single Page Application development?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application

I am new to Javascript and have started watching some Backbone.js tutorial on youtube. I have a background of working on Backend where I developed web-services.

I want to learn to develop websites using framework like backbone.js/angular.js

Comment: not here.....try google

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you should know how these framework helping you to create the Single Page Application. Take for example angularjs,

1. ng-view
2. Routing Concept.
3. Ajax Support like $http service.
4. Your back-end APIs

Creating sample Single Page Application [here](https://upvishal.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/memory-management-in-single-page-application/). Some concerns with single page application are mentioned in these two blogs.

1. [Memory Management in Single Page Application](https://upvishal.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/memory-management-in-single-page-application/)
2. [Designing Model
   for Single Page Application](https://upvishal.wordpress.com/2015/04/05/designing-model-for-single-page-application/)